# The most secure way for an .net desktop application connect to oracle database

Tags: .net, oracle, connection, odp.net, securestring

I have a **Windows Form Desktop Application** that uses odp.net to connect to an Oracle Database. The app has multiple users connecting to the same schema (the schema store a table of users for the app).

The app is installed on every client machine, Windows 7, 8, 10, and 11 desktops. (more than five hundred's in different locations and companies)

Here is a sample code to open a connection:

```
var connString = "Data Source=XE;User ID=ABC;Password=pass123";
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + conn.ServerVersion);
}
```

The problem is if someone **disassembles the code**, using tools like JetBrains dotPeek, They will be able to **read the user and key for the database**.

I got success by using an **oracle wallet** to store my password out of app code, but the wallet is a problem too since anyone who got access to the client machine can easily connect to my oracle database.

**How can I safely connect?** or safely store my oracle credentials? Is there a kind of oAuth API that returns a temporary connection key to my DB?

Comment: Create User accounts and let the users set their personal password. There is no way, when you store credentials in your application, then a hacker will be able to use this information.

Comment: The entire design is flawed: desktop software should never have credentials embedded in any way, for exactly the reasons you state, and users should always authenticate individually with their own accounts (whether authenticated at app server or at database), not as a shared application account. Does the shared account also own all of the tables and data for the application?

Comment: It doesn't even take someone disassembling code: I once evaluated a desktop financial app for which a developer had posted a code snippet online on a forum like this one. The snippet happened to contain the embedded password for all of their production databases at all of their customer locations. It was easily located in the first page of a simple Google search on the application name. Needless to say this created a bit of a stir when it was revealed to their primary customer. Don't be that app...

Comment: You mean, create a user database for every login? How can I do that automaticaly?

Comment: No - create a database or application *user* for every end user. Use database or application roles and privileges (depending on your architecture) to manage access to a common application schema. Never allow users to connect directly to a database account that owns tables or other database objects, except perhaps synonyms. How do you authenticate users individually now?

Comment: The users of app shares the same schema (user db), they are authenticated by checking a table of users

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Integrated Security=true` in the connection string and let the DBA handle Users authentication

Comment: The users access from their machines, they don't connect to an application server or use a active directory server. So I can't handle it with Integrated Security=true